# React - Canvas window does not work after centering

Tags: css, reactjs, canvas

I'm building a web app using React. I am trying to add a canvas window in which you can draw freely. but when I center this window I can no longer draw on it.
if the canvas isn't centered it works fine, but I need it to be in the center.
Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

**App**

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { Drawing } from "./components/Drawing";
import "./App.css";


function App() {

const[image, setImage]= useState();  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Drawing setImage={setImage}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
.App{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center; 
}
```

**Drawing component**

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
export function Drawing({setImage}){
    
  const colors = [
    "black",
    "red",
    "yellow",
    "green",
    "blue"
  ]

  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const ctx = useRef(null);
  const [selectedColor, setSelectedColor] = useState(colors[0]);
  const [mouseDown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);
  const[lastPosition, setPosition] = useState({x:500, y:0});
 

  useEffect(() => {
    //if the canvas is mounted
    if(canvasRef.current){
      ctx.current = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    }
  }, []);

  const draw = useCallback((x,y) => {
    if (mouseDown) {
      ctx.current.beginPath();// represent a start of drawing
      ctx.current.strokeStyle = selectedColor; //color of the line
      ctx.current.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.current.lineCap = "round";//the connection between 2 lines or more will be round and not sharp
      ctx.current.moveTo(lastPosition.x, lastPosition.y); // start from last saved location
      ctx.current.lineTo(x, y); // the new location
      ctx.current.closePath(); // close the path that was created
      ctx.current.stroke(); // without this line the drawing will not be visible
      setPosition({x,y});
      }
    },[lastPosition,mouseDown,selectedColor,setPosition])

    const onMouseDown = (e) => {
      console.log(e.pageX + " "+ e.pageY)
        setPosition({x:e.pageX, y:e.pageY});
        setMouseDown(true);
      };


      const onMouseUp = () => {
        setMouseDown(false);
       
      };
  
      const onMouseMove=(e)=>{
        draw(e.pageX, e.pageY);
      }

const clear = () =>{
  ctx.current.fillStyle = "white" //set the drawing area to white
  ctx.current.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.current.canvas.width, ctx.current.canvas.height)
}

const send = async () =>{
  const image = canvasRef.current.toDataURL('image/png');
  const blob = await(await fetch(image)).blob();
  const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = blobURL;
  setImage(blobURL);
}

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas
        style={{ border: "1px solid #000" }}
        width={400}
        height={400}
        ref={canvasRef}
        onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
        onMouseLeave={onMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
      />

      <br />
      <select
        value={selectedColor}
        onChange={(e) => setSelectedColor(e.target.value)}
      >
        {colors.map((color) => (
          <option key={color} value={color}>
            {color}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <button onClick={clear}>Clear</button>
      <button onClick={send}>Send</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```